# Utilizar IPagedList com vários resultados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itextsharp

Estou a usar o IPagedList para fazer listagem de resultados na minha aplicação. Mas estou a tentar resolver um problema: Quando tenho muitos resultados, ir à função do controller para ler os resultados de outra página fica pesado. Ou seja, quando estou a carregar a minha View estou a enviar uma lista de dados que estou a tratar com o IPagedList para fazer paginação, agora quando mudo de página não quero que vá de novo ao controller para carregar de novo a lista quando mudo de página (fica computacionalmente pesado...).

O que já tentei?

Ao fazer a query para ir buscar a lista coloquei utilizei o `Skip` e o `Take` para ir buscar apenas os resultados a apresentar na página (vem sempre ao controller cada vez que mudo a página):

```
int from = Convert.ToInt32(page) * pageSize;
int to = from + pageSize;

terceiros = terceiros.Where(k => !(fornComCert.Any(l => l.IdForn == k.IdFornecedor && l.IdFilialForn == k.IdFilial))).Skip(from).Take(to).ToList();
```

Com esta solução não calcula o número total de página e em vez de colocar todas as páginas de resultados apenas apresenta 1 página (que é a que estou a enviar em cima).

Como posso contornar isto?

Função completa:

```
public ActionResult listaFornSemCertISCC(int? page) {
        //Paginação 
        int pageSize = 20;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        ARTSOFT.dal.ViewModels.GetDadosComerciais dbArt = new ARTSOFT.dal.ViewModels.GetDadosComerciais();
        var terceiros = dbArt.getListaFornecedoresDados();
        var fornComCert = db.AutoDeclaracoesCertISCC;


        int from = Convert.ToInt32(page) * pageSize;
        int to = from + pageSize;

        terceiros = terceiros.Where(k => !(fornComCert.Any(l => l.IdForn == k.IdFornecedor && l.IdFilialForn == k.IdFilial))).Skip(from).Take(to).ToList();

        return PartialView(terceiros.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

`getListaFornecedoresDados` é uma lista:

```
public List<FornecedorCViewModel> getListaFornecedoresDados()
        { db.Open();
        //string SQLstr = "select fornumero,ternome,terfilial from TERFCH where clinumero >0";
        string SQLstr = "select fornumero,ternome,terfilial, TerNrIDFisc, DivNrFicha, TerMorada, TerLocalid, TerCPPais, TerTelef, TerTlmBip, TerFax, TerCPPais, TerTelef, TerEmail, ForCodZona, paiscod from TERFCH where terfilial = 0 AND ForNumero > 0 AND DivNrFicha != 1 AND DivNrFicha != 2 AND fornumero<>0 and Forsituac=0";
        DataTable _ret = new DataTable();
        PsqlCommand cmd = new PsqlCommand(SQLstr, db);
        PsqlDataAdapter _oDataAdapter = new PsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        _oDataAdapter.Fill(_ret);
        db.Close();
        List<FornecedorCViewModel> _lista = new List<FornecedorCViewModel>();
        foreach (DataRow row in _ret.Rows)
        {
            _lista.Add(new FornecedorCViewModel(int.Parse(row["fornumero"].ToString()), row["ternome"].ToString(), int.Parse(row["terfilial"].ToString()),
                row["TerNrIDFisc"].ToString(), int.Parse(row["DivNrFicha"].ToString()), row["TerMorada"].ToString(),
                row["TerLocalid"].ToString(), row["TerCPPais"].ToString(), row["TerTelef"].ToString(), row["TerTlmBip"].ToString(),
                row["TerFax"].ToString(), row["TerEmail"].ToString(), int.Parse(row["ForCodZona"].ToString()), int.Parse(row["paiscod"].ToString())
                ));
        }
        return _lista; }
```

Comment: função editada.

Answer (score 3):

**Faça essa otimização:**

***Ta assim:***

```
terceiros = terceiros
     .Where(k => !(fornComCert.Any(l => l.IdForn == k.IdFornecedor && l.IdFilialForn == k.IdFilial)))
     .Skip(from)
     .Take(to)
     .ToList();
```

***Coloque assim***

```
terceiros = terceiros
      .Where(k => !(fornComCert.Any(l => l.IdForn == k.IdFornecedor && l.IdFilialForn == k.IdFilial)));
```

***Ou Até***

```
public ActionResult listaFornSemCertISCC(int? page) 
{
    //Paginação 
    int pageSize = 20;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    ARTSOFT.dal.ViewModels.GetDadosComerciais dbArt = new ARTSOFT.dal.ViewModels.GetDadosComerciais();
    var terceiros = dbArt.getListaFornecedoresDados();
    var fornComCert = db.AutoDeclaracoesCertISCC;


    int from = Convert.ToInt32(page) * pageSize;
    int to = from + pageSize;

    terceiros = terceiros
        .Where(k => !(fornComCert.Any(l => l.IdForn == k.IdFornecedor && l.IdFilialForn == k.IdFilial)))            
        .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

    return PartialView(terceiros);
}
```

***Porque:***

Se dá um `ToList()` e fica trabalhando em memória com os dados isso degrada consideravelmente, então manda a `SQL` gerar tudo e depois mostrar.

***Uma Observação pertinente ao seu código***

Essa linha faz o que `dbArt.getListaFornecedoresDados();`, gera um `ToList()` se for também degrada, já começa o erro por ai. E essa  `fornComCert = db.AutoDeclaracoesCertISCC`. Aqui estão os problemas da sua geração !!! 
Outra coisa quando usa `ToPageList` não precisa usar `Skip` nem `Take` ele faz isso para você na SQL inclusive

Comment: Essa optimização realmente funciona, mas para uma listagem com cerca de 7000 registos ainda fica lenta. Porque cada vez que mudo de página vem carregar a lista de novo

Comment: Não....! o ToPagedList otimiza isso... para mim ainda tem um método `dbArt.getListaFornecedoresDados()` que ta fazendo alguma coisa de errado, tem um coisa também tire skip e take isso o ToPagegList faz pra você

Comment: @CesarMiguel tem um gargalho no seu metodo com aquele `List<FornecedorCViewModel> getListaFornecedoresDados()` como eu tinha pensado !!!!!!!!

Comment: pois, esse `dbArt.getListaFornecedoresDados()` esta a ir buscar dados a uma base de dados externa (editei o post). Eu já tirei o `Skip` e o `Take` senão não tinha conseguido apresentar todos os resultados, e criei uma nova variável para não fazer o `.ToList()`, ficando: `var result = terceiros.Where(k => !(fornComCert.Any(l => l.IdForn == k.IdFornecedor && l.IdFilialForn == k.IdFilial))).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);`

Comment: Entendi @CesarMiguel o problema então essa parte externa que ai vai ficar lento mesmo, não tem solução nesse caso, se vai ter que usar como está na primeira forma sua mesmo, eu pensei que era tudo na mesma base! como agora se explicou não tem mesmo jeito.

Comment: Pois... Não há forma de contornar a busca de resultados de uma página por javascript e em vez de ir ao controller ir buscar os próximos elementos? Foi por isso que tentei usar o `Skip` e o `Take`, mas assim ia sempre ao controller e como o return não retornava todos os elementos da lista ia perder os dados para calcular o número total de páginas.

Comment: Ou você usa um Take e Skip ou ToPageList porque eles fazem isso para você da mesma forma. Se você colocar os dois um anula o outro. Do jeito que tá é assim mesmo os dados vão ficar lento principalmente pela quantidade de registro que você me disse. Mas de vez em quando é melhor trazer do que não trazer pense assim

Comment: Exacto. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento ;)