# Paginar uma lista muito grande

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, paginação, gridview

Grid em MVC - Tenho que muitos dados para retornar e não queria trazer todos de uma só ver mesmo por que existe paginação. Como eu faço para ter 10 registros? Qual grid usar junto com MVC e Entity Framework. No exemplo abaixo eu trago tudo.

```
Itens itensmedicos = itensmedicos.where(x => x.ativos = true).ToList();
```

Coloco num grid e ele mostra certinho o único problema é que demora muito.

Comment: Não sei como é esse `itensmedicos` mas o problema é o `ToList()`. Use o que quiser para paginar, se não mudar isto você continuará com problema de performance porque você está trazendo todos os dados. Provavelmente você precisaria adaptar para algo assim `Skip(page*pagesize).Take(pagesize)`. Duas dicas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31646/padr%C3%A3o-de-nomenclatura-no-c%C3%B3digo-para-o-c/32665#32665 procure dar nomes de variáveis mais fáceis de serem lidos. Não compare contra `true` quando o resultado esperado é um booleano. Simplifique: `where(x => x.ativos)`

Comment: Há algumas respostas para perguntas muito parecidas: - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23694/pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mvc-asp-net/23697#23697 - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29722/como-uso-skip-e-take-com-o-helper-pagedlist/29821#29821 - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23398/utilizar-ipagedlist-com-v%C3%A1rios-resultados/23399#23399